# Let only one page be server-side rendered with Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor, server-side-rendering

My Meteor/React application should render one static page besides the reactive one pagers with reactive UIs. The static package does not even need to be "hydrated" with the React magic after displayed in the browser. Though the server-side rendering on the server will be dynamic with React components.

I got it working, but I'm not sure if it is the intended official way to do it.

#### File *import/client/routes.js*

```
...
<Route path="/reactive/pages/:id" component={ReactiveComponent} />
<Route path="/static_url" />
...
```

#### File *server/main.jsx*

```
...
onPageLoad((sink) => {
  if (sink.request.path === '/static_url) {
    sink.renderIntoElementById('app', renderToString(
      <StaticPage />,
    ));
  }
});
...
```

#### File *client/main.js*

```
...
import { Routes } from '../imports/client/routes';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  ...

  if (window.location.pathname !== '/offer_pdf') {
    render(Routes, document.getElementById('app'));
  }
});
...
```

Especially when rendering dependent on the URI, it seems a little bit hacky to me. Does a more elegant solution exist?

Comment: I do that too. It works but I'm not sure it's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything official, but in general, of course, it's a good idea to use a router for rendering different pages, so I thought it worth pointing out that you can use react-router on the server as well:

```
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { onPageLoad } from "meteor/server-render";
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from '/imports/ui/app.jsx';

onPageLoad(sink => {
  const context = {};
  sink.renderIntoElementById("app", renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={sink.request.url} context={context}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  ));

  /* Context is written by the routes in the app. The NotFound route, used
    when, uhm, no route is found, sets the status code. Here we set it on the
    HTTP response to get a hard 404, not just a soft 404. Important for Google bot.
  */
  context.statusCode && sink.setStatusCode(context.statusCode);

  // add title to head of document if set by route
  sink.appendToHead(`<title>${context.title || 'My page'}</title>`);
});
```

In `App` you can then use the usual `Switch` and `Route` tags for specifying different routes. In that you could, for instance, only specify routes that you want to be server-rendered.

Comment: Unfortunately neither `react-router-dom` nor `react-router` contain `StaticRouter` though it is mentioned in the docs: [https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/StaticRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/StaticRouter) (I used version 6.2.1 but they didn't change the docs vor v6)

Comment: It must be imported like this `import StaticRouter from 'react-router-dom/server';`(It is even wrong in the docs). But then I get `Error running template: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object`.

Comment: Sorry, it must be `import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom/server';`